# How to remove a substring from a string using a template function?

Tags: c++, templates

I am able to do this:

```
template <typename T>

T add (T x, T y) {
    T z = x + y;
    return z;
}

int main() {
    string string1 = "stack";
    string string2 = "overflow";
    cout << add<string> (string1, string2);
}
```

I get "stackoverflow".

How do I similarly use a template function for removing a substring from a string (that can also be used with integers, floats etc.) ? For example, remove "overflow" from "stackoverflow".

Comment: What do you mean _substracting strings_? What should `"stack" - "overflow"` yield?

Comment: What do you mean by "subtracting strings"?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry for not being clear. Edited the question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen check edit.

Comment: So what happens if the minuend does not contain the subtrahend? What happens if the minuend contains the subtrahend, but not at the end? What happens if the minuend appears in the subtrahend multiple times?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I can add exceptions for that later. For now I just need to define a function that can subtract 5 from 7 but can also remove "overflow" from "stackoverflow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I similarly use a template function for removing a substring from a string (that can also be used with integers, floats etc.) ? For example, remove "overflow" from "stackoverflow".

You can do that using a simple function like:

```
std::string remove(const std::string& toRemove, const std::string& original) {
    std::string result(original);
    size_type pos = original.find(toRemove);
    if(pos != std::string::npos) {
         result = original.substr(0,pos);
    }
    return result;
}
```

that overloads a templated version, which will apply for `float`, `int`, etc.:

```
template<typename T> T remove(const T& toRemove, const T& original) {
    return original - toRemove;
}
```

See a [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a5fc215dd38f5e8).

---

To make it work with c-style literals you may need to provide another overload:

```
std::string remove(const char* toRemove, const char* original) {
    return remove(std::string(toRemove), std::string(original));
}
```

Comment: But how will this work if I use this as a template function and pass two integers to it?

Comment: @IAA_ I extended my answer a bit.

Comment: Strange but when I pass two strings to remove() it gives me error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' and 'std::__1::basic_string<char>')

Comment: @IAA_ See my additions again.

Comment: Works fine now. I was calling it like remove<string>(string 1, string2) instead of just remove(string1, string2). Thanks again!